# Вопрос по css, не получается выровнять текст по горизонтали

Tags: css

Здравствуйте. Не получается выровнять текст по горизонтали с кнопками соц. сетей. Текст "Поделиться страницей:" всегда чуть ниже чем сама кнопка. Нужно чтобы было параллельно.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://vk.com/js/api/share.js?90" charset="windows-1251"></script>

<div class="get-code-box social content" style="border:1px double;">
 <div class="" style="display:inline-block;padding-bottom:15px;">
  Поделиться страницей:
 </div>

 <div class="" style="display:inline-block;padding-top:15px;">
  <script type="text/javascript">
  <!--
   document.write(VK.Share.button({
    url: 'http://google.ru',
    title: '',
    noparse:'true'},
    {
     type: 'button',
     text: 'Вконтакте'
    }));
   --> 
  </script>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Работает.

Comment: http://codepen.io/Geyan/pen/zBoZMa?editors=110  я почти так же сделал как soledar10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
.social{
  text-align: center;
  border:1px double;
}
.social > div{  
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  padding-top:15px;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://vk.com/js/api/share.js?90" charset="windows-1251"></script>



<div class="social content">
 <div>
  Поделиться страницей:
 </div>

 <div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  <!--
   document.write(VK.Share.button({
    url: 'http://google.ru',
    title: '',
    noparse:'true'},
    {
     type: 'button',
     text: 'Вконтакте'
    }));
   --> 
  </script>
 </div>
</div>
```